# Jquery Messagebox MVC3 when I click on a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, messagebox

I have this in my view

```
<tr>
                            <td>@Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].InsuredName</td>
                            <td>@Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].ProductType</td>
                            <td>@Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].PolicyNumber</td>
                            <td>@Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].IssueDate</td>
                            <td>@Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].Status</td>
                            <td>
                                @if (Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].CanViewContractDetails)
                                {
                                    @Html.ActionLink("View Details", "ViewContractDetails", new { @Contract=Model.EnrolledPolicies[i].PolicyNumber });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <a href="#">View Details</a>
                                }

                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

In the above else statement I would like to write some code for a Jquery message box. When I click on "View Details" from the else statement, a message box should be appearing saying Access is restricted. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery UI plugin:

```
<a href="#" class="notAllowed">View Details</a>
<div id="dialog">Access Denied</div>

$(function() {
    $('a.notAllowed').click(
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    );
});
```

Note: Style the dialog `div` by applying a class so that its hidden by default.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about JQuery. Can you Explain me in detail abt how to use a Jquery message box.

Comment: If you head over to http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message, it has excellent documentation as well as live demo.

Comment: Edited my post to remove the bad suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try this jQuery UI plugin: [JQuery UI Message Box](https://github.com/Sergik666/JQuery-UI-Message-Box)

```
<a href="#" class="DialogInfo">View Details</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a.DialogInfo').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.showMessageBox("Your message");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueryUI to do that.

Take a look at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you really need the jquery message box in this case since an alert message will satisfy your request.  FYI, the following code going to display a simple alert message when View Details is clicked

```
<a href='javascript:onClick=alert("Access is restricted")'>View Details</a>
```